# RoutingError with Nested Resources and Destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in a sort of weird situation where I'm getting a strange error with nested resources.

I have a nested resource defined as below:

```
resources :users do
  resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

My end point for comments is json only so its controller is defined as follows. Take note that I am using cancan and actsAsApi gems.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  self.responder = ActsAsApi::Responder
  respond_to :json

  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    flash[:notice] = 'Comment was successfully created.' if @comment.save
    respond_with(@comment, :api_template => :default)
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_with(@comment, :api_template => :default)
  end
```

I can then send a post request to '/users/1/comments.json' with some request parameters and the comment will get created like expected. Unfortunately I am getting an error where it tries to locate the destroy action:

```
Completed 404 Not Found in 169ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments", :id=>#<Comment id: 34, user_id: 1, text: "test test test", created_at: "2012-02-28 06:45:49", updated_at: "2012-02-28 06:45:49">}):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

As extra information, if I modify routes.rb to this:

```
resources :comments, :only => [:destroy]
resources :users do
  resources :comments, :only => [:create]
end
```

I don't see any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to figure this out. Basically it is required that when you nest resources you use respond_with as follows:

```
respond_with(@comment.note, @comment, :api_template => :default)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using nested resources you need to tell cancan to load both the users and the comments for actions on comments to work.

See as follows:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :comment, :through => :user
end
```

See more details on the [cancan nested resource page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources)